# When the array variable is considered as pointer and when it is considered as simple array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

When the array variable is considered as pointer and when it is considered as simple array in C? As example sometimes sizeof(array_variable) operator returns the address size and sometimes it returns the size of the array.

Comment: Correct answer in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597830/iterate-through-a-c-array
Search for variable-length-coder or machielo answers, and AndreyT comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C 2011 (N1570) 6.3.2.1 3:

> Except when it is the operand of the **sizeof** operator, the **_Alignof operator**, or the unary **&** operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of *type*’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

C 2011 (N1570) 6.7.6.3 7:

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of *type*’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to *type*’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the **[** and **]** of the array type derivation.

Answer (score 1):

In a function argument, an array (`[]`) or `[...]`) is equivalent to a pointer (`*`). So `sizeof(myarg) == sizeof(void*)` is true for `void f(char *myarg);`, `void f(char myarg[]);` and `void f(char myarg[42]);`.

In global and local variables, an array is different from a pointer. `sizeof(...)` reflects that difference.

An array can always be converted to a pointer automatically (but not the other way round), and the address of the first element is used, i.e. `ary` is converted to `&ary[0]`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the special case of array syntax being used in function arguments.

Comment: The C standard does not guarantee that the sizes of pointers to different types are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Always it is treated as pointer .
when you use array name without index , it will give the base address of the array . When you use the array name with index , it will be treated as *(array name + index) . It gives the indexe-th element from the base address . *array means first element .

Answer (score 0):

name of an array variable is always a pointer. It is the specilization of `sizeof()` that it returns the size of an array if applied to an array variable.

Comment: C does not have specializations. `sizeof` is an operator, not a function. It produces the size of an array when applied to an array expression, not just an array variable.