# dice roll simulator-output frequency of each roll within histogram

Tags: c, frequency, dice

I have the entire code done where the user can choose `number of sides` of the two dice, the `total number of rolls`, and it prints a `histogram of the values rolled`. I cannot figure out how to make the `frequency` of each value appear in the histogram beside their respective numbers. I have what I believe is all the relevant code, if not I will add more. I've looked through this site and found mainly `matlab code`.

```
 case 2:
     printf("\nEnter number of trials: ");
     fgets(runinput, sizeof(runinput), stdin);
     sscanf(runinput,"%d",&n);
     if (n > nmax){
         printf("Your choice of %d has exceeded the max value of trials. Value set to max of %d.",n,nmax);
         n = nmax;
         printf("\nRolling dice...");
         tried++;
     }
     else{
         printf("\nRolling dice...");
     }
     for (i=0; i <= s; i++){
         a[i] = 0;
     }
     for (i=0; i <=n-1 ; i++){
         d1 = rand()%s;
         d2 = rand()%s;
         result = d1+d2;
         x = random()%(2*s-1);
         a[result]++;
         results[i] = a;
     }
     break;
 case 3:
     if (tried != 0){
         printf("\nPrinting histogram...\n");
         for (i=0; i <= 2*s-2; i++){
             freq = results[i];
             printf("%5i|  %10i  - ", i+2, freq);
             for (j=0; j < a[i]+2; j++){
                 while (a[i] > 0){
                     if (a[i] >= 100){
                         printf("X");
                         a[i]=a[i]-100;
                     }
                     else if (a[i]>=10){
                         printf("x");
                         a[i]=a[i]-10;
                     }
                     else {
                         printf("*");
                         a[i]=a[i]-1;
                     }
                  }
              }
              printf("\n");
          }
      puts("X = 100, x = 10, * = 1\n");
      break;
```

All I'm trying to add is the frequency of which each number occurs to the histogram, any help and explanation is appreciated, I'm only in `CS239` so I'm still learning. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: what code do I need to use an array to calculate the frequency of each number rulled? I sometimes find people doing similar things but its with much more advanced programming techniques than I know how to use or will be accepted by my instructor.

Answer (score 0):

Save all the results in a single array then iterate through the array. At the end of the day you get another array and you can also iterate through it to print any value.

```
$array = [1, 6, 6, 6, 8, 9, 0,];
$counter = [];

foreach ($array as $value) {
   $counter[$value] ++;
}

print_r($counter);
```

Each **key** of the seccond array (**$counter**) has the value of the dice roll and the **$value** of that key has the frequency.

**EDIT (wrong language):**
Well, I wrote PHP instead of C; im sorry :(

You can try something close to the original idea, you can check this post on how to [Iterate through a C array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597830/iterate-through-a-c-array) and then just add a number as you find duplicate numbers into a new array and voila!

I hope this helps, again im sry about messing the languages :P

Comment: Alright thank you. I've never used $ or the foreach() function before and I don't fully understand how this would be incorporated but I will try it.

Comment: Boy I screwed that up!! :(

Comment: haha I thought it looked confusing! No worries I appreciate you taking the time to try and help a beginner.