# Opening a file and printing to a file in c

Tags: c, arrays, file

I am trying to create a file and print a series of integers through the command line. Essentially what I want is for `argv[1]` to be the first number printed and `argv[2]` to be the last number printed and the series in between. `argv[3]` will be the name of the file. My code is shown below so if anyone could point out any mistakes that would be great. Just assume for this example that the arguments received will always be four. First time using the file functions so I apologise for any really simple mistakes. Receiving an illegal array, pointer error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int array[100];
    int first, last, c;
    first=atoi(argv[1]);
    last=atoi(argv[2]);
    c=last-first;
    for (int a=0; a<c; a++) {
        array[a]=first+a;
    }
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(argv[3], "w");

    if (fp == NULL) {
       for (int i=0; i<last; i++) {
       fprintf(fp, "%d\n", array[i]);
    }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

My input is something shown below.

```
./number.c 20 25 5.txt
```

My expected output when I type cat "file_name.txt" is shown below.

```
cat number.c
20
21
22
23
24
25
```

But the output I receive is

```
ASAN:DEADLY SIGNAL

runtime error-illegal array, pointer or other operation
```

Edit: Problem solved.

Comment: Wow, sorry. Didn't even realise there was a website like that. I'll be sure to mention what is wrong next time.

Comment: Tip: when having trouble with code that has I/O, post the input used, output seen and output expected.

Comment: @Toby This question is off-topic on Code Review, and will get closed there. Read the last sentence of the prose, and the Code Review help center.

Comment: @Toby Oh, whoops, yeah. I didn't look at the timestamps. My comment is (aside from that bit accusing you of not reading the question) currently correct, though; could you remove yours to prevent confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int first, last;
    FILE *fp;

    if (argc < 3) { // Check for correct number of args
        // print an error message?
        return -1; 
    }

    first = atoi(argv[1]);
    last = atoi(argv[2]);    
    fp = fopen(argv[3], "w");

    if (fp != NULL) {
       for (int i = 0; i <= (first - last); i++) {
            fprintf(fp, "%d\n", i + first);           
        }
        fclose(fp);
    } else {
         //print an error message?
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- Removed array, since it is not needed.
- Changed the loop condition from `<` to `<=` because :

  > I want is for argv[1] to be the first number printed and argv[2] to be the last number printed and the series in between
- Moved fclose() inside the `if` because: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32674233/2394967

What you could add now is error handling(checking if the file opened successfully and checking user input), but that may not be required here.

Comment: You should check `argc` before to use `argv`.....at least....

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (fp == NULL)
```

should be changed to

```
 if (fp != NULL)
```

Comment: Is that the only thing that is wrong?

Comment: Additionally you should add some checks like - checking if user really 3 arguments on command line,if last > first, if last - first is less than 100

Comment: This is going to sound really stupid, but say I didn't know how many numbers were between last and first until I enter the command, is there anyway to make it so fprintf, doesn't print any uninitialised values.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a '}' before fclose and a ';' after fopen just to get things compiling

also the bounds of your write iteration are wrong. You should change

```
for (int i=0; i<last; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i=0; i<c; i++) {
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a simple mistake in typing for the ;. But thanks for the corrections. Apart from that is it okay?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the success of your opening before starting to read or write in the file. It will avoid a lot of times trying to understand what is not working. I am not saying it causes a problem in your code though. But might.

Try something like that :

```
file = fopen(path, mode);
if (file == NULL)
  fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file corresponding to this path : %s\n", path);
else {
  // code
}
```

Also, I would avoid iterating through an array without using the array size as loop stop condition. You could encounter segmentation faults.

Try something like that instead may be :

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.size()  1; i++) {
   fprintf(fp, "%d\n", array[i]);
}
```

In C :

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array)  1; i++) {
   fprintf(fp, "%d\n", array[i]);
}
```

More details on how to iterate an array in C [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597830/iterate-through-a-c-array).

Comment: Does array.size() work in just plain c, because all my searches point to c++?

Comment: Does not work in c++ sorry, edited.